# how keep up first drawing plot label in intra-bar?

Tags: pine-script

hi~ im pine script newbie!
i want make my script, but i faced wall.. so i need help

i make some kind of breakout indicator, that is when longcondition enter long realtime

ex)

```
study
longcondition = close >= sma(close, 3)

plot(longcondition)
```

problem is when longcondition,  i can see plot label but when price down label disappear.

i know reason,
but i wonder can i make persist plot intra-bar (even if price down  , not disappear) and discard another plot in same bar

ret me know solution, it will be great thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation the easiest answer is to use the high. The high can only increase so once it hits, it won't change.

```
longcondition = high >= sma(close, 3)

plot(longcondition)
```

As far as I know all variables roll-back on every intrabar execution, so aside from something like this I don't think there is a solution.